# AFNetworking getting data for XML parse error

Tags: objective-c, xml, xml-parsing, afnetworking, afhttpclient

This is my AFHTTPClient singleton:

```
+ (API *)sharedInstance
{
static API *sharedInstance = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    sharedInstance = [[API alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kAPIHost]];
    [sharedInstance setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
    [sharedInstance registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFXMLRequestOperation class]];
    [sharedInstance setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/rss+xml"];
});

return sharedInstance;
}
```

And method in same class (AFHTTPClient):

```
- (void)requestXMLDataCompletion:(JSONResponseBlock)completionBlock
{
NSMutableURLRequest *apiRequest = [self requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:kAPIPath parameters:nil];

AFXMLRequestOperation *operation = [[AFXMLRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:apiRequest];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
    // success
    completionBlock(responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // failure
    completionBlock([NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[error localizedDescription] forKey:@"error"]);
}];

[operation start];
}
```

When I call this function to get XML from RSS I get this error:

```
error = "Expected content type {(\n    \"application/xml\",\n    \"text/xml\"\n)}, got application/rss+xml";
```

Question:

1. Is whole concept of implemented singleton good and do I need any changes ?
2. Is there any suggestion if whole concept is wrong ?
3. Why am I getting this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **`Concept of Singleton`**

  A singleton is more commonly known as a design pattern.
  Usually a singleton is a class and behaves exactly like any other class,
  the only exception being that any instances of a singleton reference the
  same object data. This means that any instance of a singleton class are
  actually all the same instance.

You can check out [Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for more information and sample code to enforce how the singleton will be used.

- **`Is there any suggestion if whole concept is wrong ?`**

  I would suggest you to use Singleton for AFNetworking since you will have
  only one instance of it.
- **`Your Error`**

  The error you are getting is because AFNetworking request wants Header Content-Type as **"application/xml"** or **"text/xml"**

Try changing this code:

```
[self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFXMLRequestOperation class]];
```

to

```
[self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];
```

Comment: Should I even download xml data like this or is there any easier way ? I mean, this is great way of downloading json but dunno for xml. I got it with AFHTTPRequestOperation replacing AFXMLOperation in singleton and in my custom method. So I don't want to parse data with AF (will do it with GDataXML) but is this good way of downloading data ? Tnx.

Comment: Do I even need to return it in NSDictionary ? Or should I return whole data as NSArray ?

Comment: You can use NSDictionary and the user `valueForKey:` to get data.

Comment: Can you provide xml sample data.

Comment: What exactly you need to do.

Comment: Parse that feed to get text, images and stuff for every news.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30711/discussion-between-icodebuster-and-user1832330)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem:

```
Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
    "text/xml",
    "application/xml"
)}, got application/rss+xml"
```

The answer above is not full and clear, although it helped me a lot after I read their chat. `registerHTTPOperationClass` doesn't help. I decided to provide some code. Solution is to **NOT** use this:

```
[AFXMLRequestOperation XMLParserRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSXMLParser *XMLParser)
```

But download `RSS XML` using `AFHTTPRequestOperation` and create `NSXMLParser` manually:

```
NSString *articlesUrlString = @"http://pro.rabota.ru/feed/moscow.content.rss";
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:articlesUrlString]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"" parameters:nil];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

  NSData *xmlData = (NSData *)responseObject;
  NSXMLParser *XMLParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData];
  XMLParser.delegate = self;
  [XMLParser parse];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

  NSLog(@"error: %@", error);

}];
```